# How to box a polar plot with a cartesian coordinates axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want the `xy` axis to perfectly enclose the polar axis without the colorbar. So far I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Random data
r = np.random.randn(1000)
theta = np.random.randn(1000)

fig = plt.figure()

axc = plt.subplot(236)
ax = plt.subplot(236, projection='polar')
ax.set(xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[])
ax.grid(False)
hist, phi_edges, r_edges = np.histogram2d(theta, r, bins=50)
axc.set_xlim(-r_edges[-1], r_edges[-1])
axc.set_ylim(-r_edges[-1], r_edges[-1])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(phi_edges, r_edges)
pc = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, hist.T)
cbar = fig.colorbar(pc)
cbar.set_label("Counts", rotation=270, labelpad=15)
```

This produces a plot like:

[image: pic]

I want the `x` and `y` axes to align with the polar plot (and the color bar outside the axes).

Does anybody have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try binding your color bar to both of the axes and setting its location to "right":

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Random data
r = np.random.randn(1000)
theta = np.random.randn(1000)

fig = plt.figure()

axc = plt.subplot(236)
ax = plt.subplot(236, projection='polar')
ax.set(xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[])
ax.grid(False)
hist, phi_edges, r_edges = np.histogram2d(theta, r, bins=50)
axc.set_xlim(-r_edges[-1], r_edges[-1])
axc.set_ylim(-r_edges[-1], r_edges[-1])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(phi_edges, r_edges)
pc = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, hist.T)
cbar = plt.colorbar(pc, ax=[axc, ax], location='right')
cbar.set_label("Counts", rotation=270, labelpad=15)

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Great! I would only add `axc.set_box_aspect(1)` to make it align both in `x` and `y`.